# How to set an "ImageLocation"

Tags: vb.net

I am creating an app and I get an error "ImageLocation must be set"
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub changeInfo_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files|*.png; *.jpg; *.bmp"
        TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.username
        PictureBox1.Load(My.Settings.image) '<- This is the line VB highlights as an error "ImageLocation must be set"

    End Sub
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

EDIT: Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I did is that I set the ImageLocation to the FileName of the directory.

```
 Private Sub changeInfo_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files|*.png; *.jpg; *.bmp"
    TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.username
    PictureBox1.ImageLocation = My.Settings.image

End Sub
```